# Multisim Transient time point did not converge (peak detector circuit)

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, simulation, multisim, transient

I'm building a peak detector circuit with mcp6002 op amp. The signal is 8k Hz 20%dc square wave filtered through a low pass filter whose capacitor varies between about 10pf to 1000pf. The schematic is as follows.
[image]

Multisim simulation reports this error.

[image]

Any idea on how to fix the circuit or fix the software would be really appreciated. Also I was initially using lm358p instead of mcp6002 but found that the output swing doesn't cover the full range of the signal (could reach 4.5V). Is there a more suitable choice (cost is another major issue) in this case?
Thanks!

**EDIT1:**
[image]

I replace the 555 with an ideal signal source. The simulation could run a little while longer before it shuts with the same error again.

Comment: I would make two copies of the circuit, one with only the 555 circuit, the other with only the filter and peak detector. For the peak detector circuit use an ideal source to make an input signal similar to what the 555 creates (should create). Then simulate each and check that it functions properly. Now it is unclear which part causes the non convergence issue so you have to divide this into small circuits so that problems are easier to pinpoint.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thank you for the suggestion. I tried with an ideal source but the problem still exists. However the simulation could run for a little while (0.5s maybe) longer. So it seems that the peak detector part definitely has some problems.